# Forwarding mail when an individual is not CCed

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I have a client who often forgets to CC my boss. I'd like to set up a Gmail filter that detects when he isn't in the To/CC fields for e-mails from this client and forwards a copy to him.

Is this possible using Gmail's filters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `-` minus symbol to specify NOT and you can put miltiple arguments simply by separating them with a space.

**Create a filter with the following:**

**FROM**: `client@company.com`
**TO**: `me@email.com -boss@email.com`

The above filter will return emails that are **from** `client@company.com`, have been mailed **to** `me@email.com` but have **NOT** been mailed to `boss@email.com`.

Now you just need to [set that filter to auto-forward](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=10957) to you boss' email address

Answer (score 1):

Try a filter based on if the address is even in there at all. Something like the following:

> [**Doesn't have**: forgottenboss@example.com](https://mail.google.com/mail/#advanced-search/hasnot=forgottenboss@example.com)

This should highlight any incoming emails that do not contain the above email address anywhere which you could then target to forwarding on to.

To preview the filter results, run this in the search:

> [-{forgottenboss@example.com}](https://mail.google.com/mail/#search/-%7Bforgottenboss@example.com%7D)

Comment: You can also setup a forwarding address [here](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#settings/fwdandpop) so that your filter automatically forwards anything that hits the filter to your boss. **Note:** Your boss will have to give you the code that GMail sends to verify permission to do this. And don't be scared by the `Forward all your email` permission check... it doesn't auto-forward everything.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to do the trick. It appears that Gmail only searches the message body for the e-mail for the "doesn't have" filter.